# Creating a new Google Spreadsheet based on results in two sources

Tags: google-sheets

Using the "importHTML" function, I've scraped two tables from the web, containing results from weekly 5k races. These two tables now exist as two sheets within a Google Spreadsheets document, each of which are titled "19/11/11" and "12/11/11".

These sheets contain several columns, the most important of which are NAME and GRADE (a percentage value that "scores" your time based on your age.

For example:

- Max LANCASTER

  - 81.83%
- Craig MITCHELL

  - 76.58%
- Andy MCGHEE

  - 73.16%

I'd like to be able to create a new sheet with data that looks at this week's results (19/11/11) and compares it to last weeks (12/11/11). If the runner did not compete the previous week, then they are ignored, but if they did, their NAME and GRADE (for both weeks) is shown. This would allow me to sort on GRADE, and find who was the most improved runner.

Can any Google Spreadsheet experts help me figure this one out?

Thanks

Ronnie

Answer (score 1):

There's most likely better ways of doing this than what I'll suggest, but since no experts answered you... here I go!

I'll suppose NAME is on column A and GRADE on B.
In a new "compare" sheet, with the following header:
`NAME - GRADE A - GRADE B - DIFF`

I'd add these formulas on row 2.

```
A2: =Filter('19/11/11'!A2:B;Match('19/11/11'!A2:A;'12/11/11'!A:A;0))
C2: =ArrayFormula(Transpose(Split(Concatenate(If(A2:A=Transpose('12/11/11'!A2:A);Transpose('12/11/11'!B2:B);"")&If(Transpose(Row('12/11/11'!A2:A))=Rows('12/11/11'!A2:A)+1;Char(9);""));Char(9))))
D2: =ArrayFormula(FILTER(B2:B-C2:C;A2:A<>""))
```

And if I'd like the sorted result (as you mentioned), I'd do this:

```
F1: =Sort(A:D;4;false)
```